# Is there a way Spring bean afterProperties method can pick up new settings added after server startup

Tags: spring

We are constructing instance of **CouchBase cluster in Spring singleton bean afterProperties()** method by reading the configurations (like hosts, ports, connection time outs,..). This is working well.

We were using **Apache hierarchical configuration** for the configurations. Apache hierarchical configurations has **reload strategy** and does not require server restart after the configuration changed. New configurations will be reflected in 2 minutes.

Now we got requirement to update CouchBase configurations at run time. But since Spring **@afterProperties** is bean life cycle method and does not execute again, we could not able to achieve what we are looking for.

Right now, we need to **restart the server(Tomcat)** to reflect the new settings.

Is there any mechanism in Spring or any other better approach to  fulfill our requirement ( **singleton bean capable to handle configuration change at run time**).
Thinking in better design perspective, please provide your thoughts.

Comment: Perhaps a listener of some sort that would detect when the configuration changes and makes the appropriate bean changes? https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2